# QGIS, zonal statistics value is missing for a polygons

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-3, interpolation, spatial-statistics

[image]I am using India district shapefile 2011 to extract rain data. The rain data comes in point layer which I have converted to raster using "IDW interpolation" to get continuous rain data. To extract rain data at district level I am using zonal statistics. I get value for all district except one district. Can anyone help me?

[[image]